# How to use Index + Match on excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the excel commands, Index and Match to perform a task, but when using it, I keep getting an error returned. I have stated both of my arrays in my code, but I can't really seem to find out what the problem is here.

```
                     Dim WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow As Long
                     WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                     
                     Dim DeliverableDatelastRow As Long
                     DeliverableDatelastRow = .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                     
                                              
                      Set WorkOrderRange = .Range("E2:E" & WorkOrderDeliverableDatelastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                      
                      
                      
                      Set DeliverableDateRange = .Range("K2:K" & DeliverableDatelastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                      
                      
                    workOrder = Application.Index(WorkOrderRange, Application.Match(cel.Value, DeliverableDateRange, 0))
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: When I type Debug.Print workOrder, it returns Error 2042

Comment: You should first test if the result of `Application.Match` is an error.

Comment: Yes, I get the same error. I get a value for cel.Value and DeliverableDateRange, but when I combine it together, I get the error.

Comment: I'm guessing the result of `.Range("K2:K" & DeliverableDatelastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is a multi-area range, and I don't think you can use `Match` with that.